# No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I tried a simple blink for my fingerprint sensor which is GT-511C1R, but I have experienced of having an error.

> FPS_Blink.ino:12:26: fatal error: FPS_GT511C1R.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

I downloaded the whole library but still same error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is the poster's lack of basic programming skills.

Comment: If the OP has a basic lack of understanding of programming that is a valid topic for them to post about and request help.

Comment: @CodeGorilla. From Help Center, What Are Off-Topic: "Off topic: If your question is about coding not related to Arduino, try Stack Overflow.  If the solution would be the same with or without Arduino, then it's usually a general coding question."

Comment: @LookAlterno - I understand why you say that, but this is about the inability to find a file, which is an IDE setup issue.  Also I suspect the your original answer may have lost something in "translation", because it comes across quite elitist, which I'm sure is not what you meant.

Comment: @CodeGorilla. I feel this "elitist" thing is something worthy of discussion in Meta. I have already touch the subject in Meta, without any response. Have a look at my answer in https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection

Answer (score 2):

Please learn how to install a library from [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-an-arduino-library). And see if error is coming or not.